# Search Max date in an API call

Tags: json, powershell

I run an API call on midnight everyday and I wanted to capture the number of records with maximum date and the number of records can change daily.

```
$access_token ="Access_Token"

$URI =  "https://X1Y2Z3A1"
$headers = @{“authorization” = “Bearer $access_token”} 
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Headers $headers -ContentType $ContentType |ConvertTo-Json
$a = $Result|ConvertFrom-Json| Select -ExpandProperty Forms
```

```
$a

id                                     Date
--------                               -----------
A1                                     15/06/2019 16:25:46
A2                                     15/06/2019 17:26:22
A3                                     16/06/2019 13:25:46
A4                                     17/06/2019 14:21:46
A5                                     17/06/2019 15:21:46
```

I want to capture the records with maximum date as shown below:

```
Desired Result:


id                                     Date
--------                               -----------
A4                                     17/06/2019 14:21:46
A5                                     17/06/2019 15:21:46
```

Comment: i would ... sort by date descending, group by date.Split(' ')[0], select first 1, get the value in the Group of that object. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

this will get the items with the newest date [excluding the time].

what it does ...

- creates the collection to work on
  you will normally get this from Import-CSV or from the output of another code call.
- sorts by the `.Date` property, newest 1st
- groups by the date part of the `.Date` property
- selects the 1st object from the previous grouping
- gets the value in the `.Group` property of the previous object
- puts that into the `$NewestDateList` variable
- displays that $Var

the only likely glitch with this is the way date strings are handled. i suspect that any serious variation in format would require explicitly parsing the dates.

here's the code ...

```
# fake reading in a CSV file OR getting a array of objects
#    in real life, use Import-CSV OR get the array from calling another source
$InStuff = @'
id, Date
A1, 15/06/2019 16:25:46
A2, 15/06/2019 17:26:22
A3, 16/06/2019 13:25:46
A4, 17/06/2019 14:21:46
A5, 17/06/2019 15:21:46
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$NewestDateList = ($InStuff |
    Sort-Object -Property Date -Descending |
    Group-Object -Property {$_.Date.Split(' ')[0]} |
    Select-Object -First 1).
    Group

$NewestDateList
```

output ...

```
id Date               
-- ----               
A5 17/06/2019 15:21:46
A4 17/06/2019 14:21:46
```

Comment: @Lee_Daily this works perfectly if I have commas in my array (,) between the columns which I don't.

Comment: @Djbril - so ... what do you have? your sample data is an array of objects that have two properties - `ID` and `Date`. my code has a comment that specifically says the 1st part is **_faking_** reading in a CSV file OR using a command to get an array of objects. the entire part before the `$NewestDateList = ($InStuff |` line is for setting up some test data. it has NOTHING to do with how you get your real data into the script.